# Why do I get this error with setAdapter()?

Tags: android, adapter

Why do I get this error with setAdapter()?

[image: see this picture]

The source is:

```
exercise_listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.activity_sports_calories_list);
exercise_listView.setAdapter(new SportsCaloriesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),exercise_list));
```

Comment: Hover over it... what does it say?

Comment: SportCaloriesAdapter()  in SportsCaloriesAdapter  cannot be applied (android.content.Context, java.util.List)

Comment: Could you post your `SportCaloriesAdapter` class code?

Comment: I wrote "void" in the " public SportsCaloriesAdapter(Context context, List exercise_list){....} ". After I delete " void ", it was ok. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SportsCaloriesAdapter class. You must implement in it a constructor with Context and List as parameters.

Comment: I wrote "void" in the " public SportsCaloriesAdapter(Context context, List exercise_list){....} ". After I delete " void ", it was ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Didn't define list Type use this i think the error for this

```
List<String>exercise_list;
```

Comment: I had defined  exercist_list in the onCreate();    List exercise_list;

Comment: oh Check it a gain you have to define Type As String but you didn't set id

@Nola